# Append the results of NSFetchedResultController to an array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I want to display the results of an `NSFetchedresultController` in a separate section of a `UITableview`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always access all the fetched objects of NSFetchedResultsController by using

```
self.yourFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
```

You can always carefully unwrap the fetchedObjects

```
if let arrayOfYourObjects = self.yourFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects {
     otherArray.appendContentsOf(arrayOfYourObjects)
}
```

Hope it helps